# PHP sessions do not pass variables to the other page

Tags: php

I know that if i want to pass variables in php from a page to another one I can use sessions, but I don't know what is wrong with this code, it's just doesn't work,
I want to pass the $cout variable from page 1 to page 2

**PAGE 1**

```
<?php 
session_start();


if(isset($_POST['date']))
{
    $dat = $_POST['date'];
    $matricule = $_POST['matricule'];
    $kilometrage = $_POST['kilometrage'];
    $num_fact = $_POST['num_fact'];
    $Fournisseur = $_POST['Fournisseur'];
    $num_bon = $_POST['num_bon'];
    $Fonctionnaire = $_POST['Fonctionnaire'];
    $cout = $_POST['cout'];

    //here is all what I did 
    $_SESSION['cout'] = $_POST['cout'];

    header("Location: PAGE2.php")    ;

}

?>
```

and here is PAGE 2:

```
<?php 
session_start();
 $cout = $_SESSION['cout'];
 echo $cout ;?>
```

and here is the form

```
<form method="post" action="page1.php" >
            <input type="date" placeholder="La Date Ex: 2014-07-17" name="date"><br>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Matricule" name="matricule"><br>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Kilometrage" name="kilometrage"><br>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Numero de facteur" name="num_fact"><br>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Fournisseur" name="Fournisseur" ><br>
            <input type="text" placeholder="N° de bon à delivrer au fornisseurs ou facture" name="num_bon"><br>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Fonctionnaire ayant effectué la Réparation" name="Fonctionnaire" ><br>
            <input type="text" placeholder="le coût de la reparation en DH" name="cout" ><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Valider">
        </form>`
```

Comment: have you used `session_start();` on the first page?

Comment: Use `session_start();` at top of the **page1** also.

Comment: I think he probably already done this. But maybe, the session stuff is not the problem. Have you dump the $_POST['cout'] and check if there is something in it ?
And what about the $_SESSION['USR'] ? If it's not set, the code of the page 1 isn't executed at all.

Comment: i already used session_start(); yes, but i didn't dump anything , who to do so ?

Comment: Be sure to place an `exit;` behind a `header('Location: ..);`

Comment: What about your form in HTML? Is there an element with `name=cout`? In this piece of PHP code shouldn´t be problem.

Comment: @DarkBee: not necessary, in this case it´s the last command in file. Problems are caused by anything else.

Comment: **first thing** line 3 is useless
if in page 2, undefined index error is not being shown, `$_SESSION['cout']` was set to `''`, that means `$_POST['cout']` was `''`

Comment: @panther yes it exists.

Comment: @Hamzaouiii : just put var_dump($_POST['cout']); before your session assignment to check if tehere is something in it.
If nothing is printed on your page, it's maybe not the session which doesn't not work

Comment: vardump your $_POST and make sure there are values

Comment: Thanks Rob .. but you're late from 8 comments ..

Comment: Show us your form, what is in `action` param? Are you sure you send form to page1.php?

Comment: Turn on errors reporting

Comment: @ThomasLeduc it does actually does print the value of my cout variable on the top of the page

Comment: @panther I will add it now

Comment: Ok, now can you put var_dump($_SESSION) after the session_start() on page 2

Comment: @ThomasLeduc: it has to be empty.

Comment: @Hamzaouiii: what about `var_dump($_POST)` in page1.php before `$dat = ...` (line 7). Is there everything right, are in POST any data? If so, try to `echo $_SESSION['cout']; exit;` before `header()`, if SESSION is filled correctly.

Comment: I don't know what you mean guys ?

Comment: @panther : the $_POST['cout'] dump is ok, it's all we need to know for this issue.

Comment: And the second part of my previous comment? Try to print session, if it´s filled (i´ve edited my comment later)

Comment: I wonder if he already solved it.. '@ThomasLeduc it does actually does print the value of my cout variable on the top of the page –  Hamzaouiii 17 mins ago' :D

Comment: @Toly no it didn't... when i wrote var_dump($_POST['cout']); it just wrote the value of the cout input, but the echo statement did nothing

Comment: Well, your code works. Just tested it myself. Are both page1 and page2 in the same folder?

Comment: Also, when submitting the form - check that both date and cout fields are not empty. Your code works the way that if cout is empty - it will show nothing.

Comment: Oh my god, is PHP case sensitive ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems correct, but dependant on the existence of $_POST['date'] variable.

When you submit the form - please make sure that it is not empty.

**EDIT2:**

I have made two files on my own, your code works fine.

You'll need to look for error on part of server php config, or pathways.

Try following: (assuming page1.php and page2.php are in root folder of your site)

```
in html
<form action="/page1.php" ..

in page1
header("Location: /page2.php");
```

Comment: `isset($_POST['date'])` will be `TRUE` if this field will be empty too.

Answer (score 0):

Try isset($_POST['submit']) in place of isset($_POST['date']). I think you are not filling date.

Comment: He filled date, because redirect (`header` function) is inside the condition.

Answer (score 0):

May be your temp folder is write protected. Check `session_save_path()` is writable or not.